# Matlab multidimensional feature SVM

Tags: matlab, svm

I have a little problem with SVM classifier in Matlab. I have a 61200x59 matrix of features in which each row represent a set of features extracted from an image (all double values). All those features are associated with a 61200x1 matrix containing 2 labels: 0 and 1 (as double variables). Now I want to train a linear classifier and I've used the following function:

```
SVM_Model = fitcsvm(train_features, train_labels, 'KernelFunction', 'linear')
```

If I take a look to the details of this line I obtain this result:

```
SVM_Model = 
  ClassificationSVM
             ResponseName: 'Y'
    CategoricalPredictors: []
               ClassNames: [0 1]
           ScoreTransform: 'none'
          NumObservations: 61200
                    Alpha: [40956×1 double]
                     Bias: 0.9998
         KernelParameters: [1×1 struct]
           BoxConstraints: [61200×1 double]
          ConvergenceInfo: [1×1 struct]
          IsSupportVector: [61200×1 logical]
                   Solver: 'SMO'
```

But when I call the predict function on test set (`[label, score] = predict(SVM_Model, test_features(i, :));`) it predicts always the label 1 (on over than 15000 test, so it seems a little bit suspicious) and on all the class 0 object I have a classification error. Can anyone tell me what can be the problem? Is necessary to rescale the features because SVM cannot handle high-dimensional points? Or another problem is present (like misconfiguration is SVM learning)?

Comment: I never used Matlab's SVM, but from my experience with LibSVM, I suggest your run `all(isfinite(train_features(:)))`. If the output is `0`, then your feature matrix has non-numeric values such as NaN and Inf. LibSVM could not find support vectors in that case; you might be running into the same problem.

Comment: Thank you. Just tried but result gives 1. I'm sure that train and label sets are correct.

Comment: Then I suggest you try a different kernel. If it still doesn't work, I suggest you download Weka and experiment different parameter settings.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with different kernels and tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HIK kernel everything works fine. Also using RBF kernel gives good result on this problem.